# Pass custom context into OnRetry

Tags: c#, polly, retry-logic

- I would like to use Polly **v8**, which introduces new `ResiliencePipeline` API.
- I would like to use `ResiliencePipeline.ExecuteAsync()` to handle the execution of provided asynchronous action using the `Retry` strategy.
- I would need to have custom context available in `OnRetry` callback, which is defined upon `ResiliencePipeline` building phase (via `ResiliencePipelineBuilder`).
- It looks like there is only an `OnRetryArguments` available in the `OnRetry` callback.
- If I haven't missed anything, only `Context` property (of `ResilienceContext` type) could be used for custom data passing, namely the `Properties` (of `ResilienceProperties` type).

I haven't found any way, how to "configure" the particular `ResilienceContext` instance used in given `ExecuteAsync` call, other than creating it by myself and passing it directly to the appropriate overload. This seems a bit complicated, as it needs to take instance from a pool and then return it back after the execution is finished (looks like `ResilienceContextPool.Shared` could serve it).

Is this the preferred way, or am I missing something obvious?

Is the `ResilienceContextPool.Shared` considered to be used for these purposes?

**EDIT:**

```
public static class ResiliencePipelineExtensions
{
    public static async ValueTask ExecuteAsync(this ResiliencePipeline resilience, Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask> action, string operation, IDictionary<string, object> context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var resilienceContext = ResilienceContextPool.Shared.Get(operation, cancellationToken);

        foreach (var property in context)
        {
            resilienceContext.Properties.Set(new ResiliencePropertyKey<object>(property.Key), property.Value);
        }

        try
        {
            await resilience.ExecuteAsync(ctx => action(ctx.CancellationToken), resilienceContext);
        }
        finally
        {
            ResilienceContextPool.Shared.Return(resilienceContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Looks like this works as expected...

Comment: Which pre-release version of V8 are you playing with?

Comment: Latest available on nuget. Will need to go through the sources, as neither the method described above works (the context passed to the ExecuteAsync won't show up in the OnRetry).

Comment: Never mind, there was a forgotten async/await in the method. It works. So the question is: is it intended to be so "complicated" to use brand new API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing this post Polly V8 is not yet finished. Currently the V8 beta 2 is available which means it is feature ready and the API considered (mostly) stable.

*That means there is still a chance to have an impact on how the V8 API should look like.* There have already been a couple or public API review sessions and lots of suggestion have been accepted and incorporated into the code base.

So, if you find the current API is hard to use then please feel free to file an issue on Polly's github.

For example the current implementation of [`ResilienceProperties`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/2c5fc268ce253f9e9be9a318bd592f4de54b874a/src/Polly.Core/ResilienceProperties.cs) does not allow "bulk load" of key value pairs. But under the hood it is using a `Dictionary<string, object?>` collection. It might be a good feedback to extend this class with "bulk load" capability.

---

> is it intended to be so "complicated" to use brand new API?

V8 is way different than what we had in the previous years. It is a complete rewrite and a couple of new design principles have been embraced.

### Async from ground-up

Like for instance the API is from ground-up async. That means all user-defined delegates should be async as well. In previous pre-release versions you had to write some boiler-plate code to use the API in synchronous fashion

```
ShouldRetry = outcome => new ValueTask<bool>(outcome.Exception is TimeoutRejectedException),
```

but based on the feedbacks some helper classes have been introduced as well as a couple of implicit conversion operators

```
ShouldRetry = new PredicateBuilder().Handle<TimeoutRejectedException>()
```

### Expose similar API

Also V8 tries to follow couple of .NET conventions that have been battle hardened in the previous years. Like the `ResilienceContextPool`'s API has a huge resemblance of `ArrayPool` (*with some exceptions, like `.Shared.Get` needs to be used instead of `.Shared.Rent`*).

### Reuse existing components

Another example is that .NET 7 has introduced [`RateLimiter`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-rate-limiting-for-dotnet/) and rather than having two separate implementations Polly V8 uses that component. Of course some wrappers had to be introduced to nicely integrate with other strategies and with the pipeline builder.

```
new ResiliencePipelineBuilder()
    .AddRateLimiter(new RateLimiterStrategyOptions());

new ResiliencePipelineBuilder()
    .AddConcurrencyLimiter(100, 50);
```

### Minimize input parameters

Yet another design principle was to minimize the number of input parameters. In case of V7 there were several overloads for `onRetry` for example. Each overload provided access to different parameters and it was quite hard sometimes to find the appropriate overload.

In case of V8 you have a single `XYZOptions` parameter for the builder methods and `XYZArguments` for user-defined delegates.

---

The above list is not exhaustive but I hope this little background information provided you a bit of context why does the V8 API look as it is.

Comment: Thank you, I have read the stuff about v8, considered it as "stable enough" and as I was impressed by the benchmarks comparing v7 and v8, so I was thinking v8 is worth the try.

Comment: @sharpener I did not mention explicitly but performance was an explicit goal as well. In the new code base you can see a tons of optimizations to reduce memory footprint and optimize resource usage. But with many general purpose tool the execution speed mainly depends on the user provided code. Here the main aim was to introduce as low overhead as possible by utilizing the most modern C# and .NET features.