How to institute logging from Poly ResiliencePipeline for success after failure
In C# I'm using Polly Version=8.4.1 and a reusable retry ResiliencePipeline via ResiliencePipelineBuilder.
    return new ResiliencePipelineBuilder()
        .AddRetry(new RetryStrategyOptions
        {
            MaxRetryAttempts = 5,
            DelayGenerator = {blah(blah, blah);},
            ShouldHandle = args => { blahblah(blah); }
        }).Build();

I want to be able to add logging for when the operation initially fails but subsequently succeeds.  Something like:
{operations} recovered after 3 tries, in 22 seconds

I believe in older versions of Polly this would be accomplished by injecting handling via the OnSuccess operation.
How is this done in v8.x?

On way to solve this problem is by introducing a custom ResilienceStrategy. This strategy wraps your retry strategy and captures the execution time via a simple Stopwatch. It also retrieves the attempt count via the usage of ResilienceContext.
Here you can find a working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9uEFbl.
The custom strategy
public sealed class RetryReporterStrategy: ResilienceStrategy
{
    private readonly ResiliencePropertyKey<int> _attemptCount;
    public RetryReporterStrategy(ResiliencePropertyKey<int> attemptCount)
    {
        _attemptCount = attemptCount;
    }

    protected override async ValueTask<Outcome<TResult>> ExecuteCore<TResult, TState>(
        Func<ResilienceContext, TState, ValueTask<Outcome<TResult>>> callback,
        ResilienceContext context,
        TState state)
    {
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var result = await callback(context, state).ConfigureAwait(context.ContinueOnCapturedContext);
        watch.Stop();

        context.Properties.TryGetValue(_attemptCount, out var attempts);
        if (result.Exception is not null)
            Console.WriteLine($"The operation failed after {attempts+1} tries, in {watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} seconds");
        else
            Console.WriteLine($"The operation succeeded after {attempts+1} tries, in {watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} seconds");

        return result;
    }
}


The strategy receives a ResiliencePropertyKey which is used to set & get the attempt number on the context

The attempt number for the retry strategy starts from 0 because the original user function's execution does not count as retry


The ExecuteCore starts the stopwatch, executes the wrapped strategy (var result = await callback(...)` and stops the stopwatch
Then it fetches the attempt count

Please bear in mind that this code demonstrates the basic idea WITHOUT any proper error handling
In your production code please make sure that TryGetValue returns true before you start using the attempts variable


Before the function returns the result it performs some logging

This branching logic is meant only for demonstration
In your production code it could be more sophisticated



Let's wire up
public static class RetryExtensions
{ 
    public static ResiliencePipelineBuilder AddFancyRetry(this ResiliencePipelineBuilder builder, RetryStrategyOptions options)
    {
        ResiliencePropertyKey<int> attemptCountKey = new(nameof(attemptCountKey));
        return builder
        .AddStrategy(context => new RetryReporterStrategy(attemptCountKey), options)
        .AddRetry(new() {
            BackoffType = options.BackoffType,
            Delay = options.Delay,
            DelayGenerator = options.DelayGenerator,
            MaxDelay = options.MaxDelay,
            MaxRetryAttempts = options.MaxRetryAttempts,
            Name = options.Name,
            Randomizer = options.Randomizer,
            OnRetry = args =>
            {
                args.Context.Properties.Set(attemptCountKey, args.AttemptNumber);
                return options.OnRetry?.Invoke(args) ?? default;
            },
            ShouldHandle = options.ShouldHandle,
            UseJitter = options.UseJitter
        });
    }
}


An extension method is defined against ResiliencePipelineBuilder to ease the usage

In your production code you might need to introduce a generic variant as well against the ResiliencePipelineBuilder<TResult> type


First the function defines a ResiliencePropertyKey which is used for communication (via the context) between our custom strategy and the retry
It registers our RetryReporterStrategy first as the outer strategy into the pipeline (.AddStrategy)
Then it adds a retry as the inner strategy (.AddRetry)

It basically copies blindly all values from the options parameter, except for OnRetry

First it sets the attempt number on the context
Then it performs the OnRetry delegate if it was provided





Usage samples
A happy path
var pipeline = new ResiliencePipelineBuilder()
    .AddFancyRetry(new () {
        ShouldHandle = args => PredicateResult.True(),
        MaxRetryAttempts = 3,
        Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
    })
    .Build();

await pipeline.ExecuteAsync(async ct => await Task.Delay(100, ct), CancellationToken.None);

The output
The operation succeeded after 3 tries, in 3.4203751 seconds


The Task.Delay have been executed four times >> 0.4s

Four times: the original attempt + three retry attempts


Before each retry attempt the strategy waited a second >> 3.0s
and finally there is a negligible Polly pipeline overhead >> 0.02s

An unhappy path
pipeline = new ResiliencePipelineBuilder()
    .AddFancyRetry(new () {
        ShouldHandle = new PredicateBuilder().Handle<Exception>(),
        MaxRetryAttempts = 5,
        Delay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500),
        OnRetry = static args => 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnRetry");
            return default;
        }
    })
    .Build();

await pipeline.ExecuteAsync(async ct => 
{ 
    await Task.Delay(100, ct); 
    throw new Exception(); 
}, CancellationToken.None);

The output
OnRetry
OnRetry
OnRetry
OnRetry
OnRetry
The operation failed after 5 tries, in 3.1136394 seconds
Unhandled exception. System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.

In this scenario we had

6 execution attempts >> 0.6s
5 half second delays >> 2.5s
and the Polly overhead >> 0.01s


Thanks for the complete solution. It would have taken a lot of research before I stumbled on ResiliencePropertyKey for injecting the retry count into the ResilienceContext.
I’m also interested in tracking the total time performing the operation, but for that I would need to initialize the property value once per Execute call.  I presume the best solution would be something like the question suggests @ https://stackoverflow.com/q/77118075/202068.  ?

@rediVider So, in Polly V8 we have context and state. Here we detailed the differences and here the usage of the context. You could not create a custom OnRetryArguments but you can create a custom RetryStrategyOptions like the HttpRetryStrategyOptions.
